# Laravel update how to update data in index

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The problem is i want to skip that edit page. it works as fine. but i wanna edit my data in index view.

**i tried this but i took this error**

```
{!! Form::model($choice, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['choices.update', $choice->id]]) !!}
  <input class="form-control" value="@foreach ($choices as $choice){{ $choice->question_number }}@endforeach" type="number" name="number"></input>
{!! Form::submit('Update Task', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\zainsurgalt\resources\views\choices\index.blade.php)

**index view**

```
<td><a href="{{ route('choices.edit', $duplicate->topic->id) }}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a></td>
```

**edit view**

```
{!! Form::model($choice, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['choices.update', $choice->id]]) !!}
    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="number"></input>
{!! Form::submit('Update Task', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**controller update**

```
public function update(Request $request,Choice $choice){
     Choice::where('id', $choice->id)->update([
        'question_number' => $request->input('number')
        ]);
  return redirect()->route('choices.index');
}
```

Comment: use a modal instead to appear when you click edit

Comment: oh nice idea. i forgot about modal. can you provide any good example?

Comment: Why you applying foreach in value in modal

Comment: I think you already get that question_number in `{{ $choice->question_number }}`...

Comment: Are you check **$choice, $duplicate->topic** empty or not??

Comment: Yes i checked. wasn't empty

Comment: what about **$duplicate->topic**?? empty or not??

Comment: Yep. 100% sure. it wasnt empty. it had 34records.

Comment: It is fix your problem?

Comment: no I didn't fix it. but i managed to gamble it by using Modal.

Answer (score 1):

All time when you get object property you must be check object exist or not

```
@if (!empty($duplicate->topic))
    <td><a href="{{ route('choices.edit', $duplicate->topic->id) }}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a></td>
@endIf
```

also

```
@if (!empty($choice))
    {!! Form::model($choice, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['choices.update', $choice->id]]) !!}
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="number"></input>
    {!! Form::submit('Update Task', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endIf
```

and finally you use

```
@foreach ($choices as $choice){{ $choice->question_number }}@endforeach
```

change `$choice` to another name for example `$_choice` , for not confusing above used `$choice`